# Serving static files when in deployment mode with debug = false

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I have deployed my app on heroku and I am serving static files using `whitenoise`.
Everything works perfectly, but when I turn `debug=false` the css stops being rendered.What could be the issue here? The static files are not be supplied by django but by `whitenoise`.Can't figure it out.

relevant `settings.py`

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
 STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

project's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('watch.urls', namespace="watch")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template's static file declaration

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/finale.css' %}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start by following the [documentation on using WhiteNoise with Django](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html) more closely. The first difference I see is that your line:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

differs from the docs:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

If following that tutorial doesn't work you should make sure to include all the relevant parts of your app (e.g., I'd need to see `wsgi.py` along with the files you show above) including all the `WHITENOISE_XXXXXX` settings in your `settings.py` to figure out the issue.